# Is it possible to change the resolution from outside the game in Age of Empires 1?

Tags: age-of-empires

I would like to change the screen resolution in Age of Empires 1. Is it possible to do so from outside the game?

Answer (score 5):

> **Not officially no, but you can use upatch-hd!**

There is no official way of changing the resolution outside the game with Age of Empires, but you can use [upatch](http://www.moddb.com/mods/upatch-hd).

**What upatch-hd is:**

> UPatch is unofficial update (user patch) for Age of Empires: The Rise of Rome Expansion (only). A solid improvement over the original game, UPatch features custom game resolutions (up to 1920x1200), over 150 bug fixes, new gameplay options and other enhancements. UPatch will update your game to version 1.1. Included languages are German, French, Spanish, Portuguese and Italian (you can select language when installing).

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know, but it's only for the The Rise of Rome Expansion though :(

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The sad part is that there is no other option. You can't change the resolution any other way, because high resolutions are not supported by the game directly. There's no work around that (officially) and it's the case with all dated games.

Comment: If you want to ONLY change the resolution then you may have problems using this patch.  There seems to be some balance changes/tweaks to the game.  If you are happy with the changes it introduces then this patch is fine to use.  As already pointed out, it seems to only change the Rise of Rome / Gold Edition version of the game.

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility on SourceForge called DxWnd:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dxwnd/

It allows you to run pretty much **any** game in windowed mode, including Age of Empires.

I use this program to play the game so know it works.

It works by intercepting system calls regarding full-screen mode and translates them into a resizeable window.